# Elastic beanstalk autohealing when celery tasks error

Tags: python, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-celery

Elastic beanstalk can find http error and de-regist that instance.

but can't find celery tasks error.

how i can auto de-regist wrong instance when have issue celery task?

Comment: Celery should not run in your ElasticBeanstalk infrastructure. If it does, then you are doing it wrong I think.

Comment: Then, celery should to run where you think?

Comment: You should manage Celery cluster separately, and your service(s) running in ElasticBeanstalk should offload stuff to your Celery cluster. Task errors do happen, and there are many ways to address this (retries, ignores, etc)